# How can I arrange the !help command categories so they aren't in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'd like to have my !help command set up so that it displays user commands, mod commands, admin commands, and then, finally, my commands. However, by using cogs to sort these into categories, they are loaded in alphabetically, which leads to admin being the first seen due to it starting with an A.

This is for my Discord bot, Maximus. I've tried changing the order of the `bot.load_extension`. However, this has had no change to the categories.
This is the !help command:

```
    Admins:
      purge     Deletes a specific amount of messages
    Members:
      hello     Max says hello!
      joined    Max will tell you when you joined the server!
      report    
      rndatk    Max will pick some attacking ops for you
      rnddef    Max will pick some defending ops for you
      say       Max says what you say!
      version   
    Mods:
      mute      
    Owner:
      logout     

    Type !help command for more info on a command.
    You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

I'd like the order it is displayed as to be Members, Mods, Admin, and finally, Owner; Members being at the top and Owner being at the bottom.

EDIT:

Here are the 4 `bot.load_extension` that load 4 separate cogs. Each corresponding to a category in !help:

```
bot.load_extension("cogs.Users")
bot.load_extension("cogs.Admin")
bot.load_extension("cogs.Mods")
bot.load_extension("cogs.Owner")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, describe specific problem and provide your code

Comment: If you read the second paragraph you can see what I've tried doing

Comment: maybe try making it yourself? unless its a huge bot it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [built-in part of the default help formatter](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/1863a1c6636f53592519320a173ec9573c090c0b/discord/ext/commands/formatter.py#L336).

To change this behavior, you'll have to subclass [`HelpFormatter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpFormatter), override [`format()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpFormatter.format), and specify an instance of your subclass as the [`formatter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.formatter) when you initialize the [`Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot).